# Load the scene when all enemies die

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am creating a laser defender game in unity and I have this problem where when I shoot the first enemy it takes me directly to the NextLevelMenu scene but I want it to load when all the enemies are killed(on this level I have 5 enemies to kill). I have been told that I need to send a reference to the instance of its spawner to every spawned enemy but I did not quite understand. Can someone help, please?

EnemySpawner Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class EnemySpawner : MonoBehaviour {

[SerializeField] GameObject EnemyPreFab;
[SerializeField] int MaxEnemies = 30;
[SerializeField] float EnemySpawnTime = 1.00001f;
[SerializeField] GameObject FirstWaypoint;
int CurrentNumOfEnemies = 0;
public LevelManager myLevelManager;
public int maximumnumberofhits = 0;
public static EnemySpawner Instance = null;
int timesEnemyHit;




IEnumerator SpawningEnemies()
{
    while(CurrentNumOfEnemies <= MaxEnemies)
    {
        GameObject Enemy = Instantiate(EnemyPreFab, this.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        CurrentNumOfEnemies++;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(EnemySpawnTime);
    }
}

void Start()
{
    if (Instance == null)
        Instance = this;
    StartCoroutine(SpawningEnemies());
    timesEnemyHit = 0;
    if (this.gameObject.tag == "EnemyHit")
    {
        CurrentNumOfEnemies++;
    }


}

public void OnEnemyDeath()
{
    CurrentNumOfEnemies--;
    if (CurrentNumOfEnemies < 1)
    {
        // You killed everyone, change scene: 
        LaserLevelManager.LoadLevel("NextLevelMenu");
    }
 }


}
```

EnemyShooting script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyShooting : MonoBehaviour {


[SerializeField] float EnemyLaserSpeed = 10f;
[SerializeField] float EnemyLaserFireTime;
[SerializeField] GameObject LaserBulletEnemyPreFab;
[SerializeField] int MaxNumberOfHits = 1;

int CurrentNumberOfHits = 0;
Coroutine FireCoroutine;

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider)
{
    if(collider.gameObject.tag == "PlayerLaser")
    {
        if(CurrentNumberOfHits < MaxNumberOfHits)
        {
            CurrentNumberOfHits++;
            Destroy(collider.gameObject);
            Score.ScoreValue += 2;//The user will be rewarded 1 point
        }
    }
}


void DestroyEnemy()
{
    if(CurrentNumberOfHits >= MaxNumberOfHits)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
        EnemySpawner.Instance.OnEnemyDeath(); // Tell the EnemySpawner that someone died


    }
}

private void Fire()
{
    FireCoroutine = StartCoroutine(ShootContinuously());
}

void BecomeVisible()
{
    Fire();
}

IEnumerator ShootContinuously()
{
    while (true)
    {
        GameObject LaserBulletEnemy = Instantiate(LaserBulletEnemyPreFab, this.transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        LaserBulletEnemy.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(0, EnemyLaserSpeed);
        EnemyLaserFireTime = Random.Range(0.5f, 0.9f);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(EnemyLaserFireTime);
    }
}
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    BecomeVisible();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    DestroyEnemy();

    }
  }
```

Comment: You could change currentNumberOfEnemies to numberOfEnemiesForLevel, instantiate it at the number of enemies you want for that level (i.e. 5 for this one) and then remove the increment from the spawn script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add a two fields to the spawner script. EnemiesToNextLevel and KilledEnemies. Then in the OnEnemyDeath() of your spawner, you may increase KilledEnemies everytime it is called, and then ask if KilledEnemies >= EnemiesToNextLevel, before changing the scene.

Sure there are a lot of other ways to do it, but for me thats the easiest.

Comment: Just to be sure, so in OnEnemyDeath() I add KilledEnemies++; and in the same function I add if(KilledEnemies>=EnemiesToNextLevel){ LaserLevelManager.LoadLevel("NextLevelMenu")}

Comment: Yes, that does the trick. Then for each level you will want to set EnemiesToNextLevel to a given value and set KilledEnemies to 0.

Comment: So for level 2 I'm gonna have 10 enemies I set Enemiestonextlevel =10; and killedenemies = 0;

Comment: The one you already have serves no purpose after you added the checks on the response.